# Why are thresholds for energy detection and preamble detection different in 802.11 standard?

Tags: energy

Assuming a 20 MHz band, it is -62 dBm for the data and -82 dBm for the preamble. 
Source: August 2013 doc.: IEEE 802.11-13/0994r0

Comment: The preamble is longer. This is the threshold of detection.

Comment: I can't see the relation between having a longer preamble needing less energy to detect, unless the detection process function is like an accumulator. Some other sources mentioned "If you would "sleep" at -62dBm you would consume more power during idle state compared to -82dBm." so it's because to save energy, but I dn't understand the logic in this case too.

Answer (score 1):

Although the preamble is longer, it is due to a lower bit rate that it has a lower threshold.   In 802.11g, the PHY layer combines a DSSS preamble with OFDM payload transmission.

-

The 2013 standard indicates that the Synchronization and Start Frame Delimiter
(SFD) fields are transmitted at 1 Mbps. The rest of the header is sent at 2 Mbps
(DQPSK) and the data payload is sent using DQPSK at 2 Mbps or CCK at 5.5 or
11 Mbps or more.

The threshold depends on the data rate which demonstrates the **Hartley's Law** tradeoff between SNR and Bit rate for the the same bit error rate... * [Hartley's Law compared to Shannon–Hartley theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem#Comparison_of_Shannon's_capacity_to_Hartley's_law)

*(and I did not mean the Arizona's **Shannon Law** that forbid's shooting a gun up in the air)*

The **20dB rise in Rx level** is needed to achieve either the max rate in the 20MHz Band  using  higher-order modulation such as 256QAM.

This is why Modems will automatically reduce bit rates when packet error rates exceed some threshold. Normally -70 dBm is more than enough for 54Mbps.

### Anecdotal

Although from my experience when Rician Fading (Echo interference) is dominant , and the RSSI is between -75 and lower levels, that you get higher thruput using 11Mb/s than leaving it on 54Mbps which often drops near 1Mbps rates when it momentarily drops to -80dBm.